# Check RSS feed and post to Discord

Tags: javascript, promise, discord

I'm new to using JS for anything other than DOM manipulation, so I'm not sure if the following code is taking full advantage of the Async concept in JS.

This is an example of a function I'm writing in my Discord.js bot project. The function checks for new RSS feed items from a given URL and then calls another function that posts the new items as Discord messages:

```
const postLatestFeed = () => {
   console.log("Checking for new feed...");
   let postFeedPromise = DataService.GetLastChackDate() // GetLastChackDate() is a promise
       .then((lastCheckDate) => {
          console.log("Last check date is:");
          console.log(lastCheckDate);
          return RssService.GetRssItems(RSS_FEED_URL, lastCheckDate);
       })
       .then((rssItems) => {
          console.log("Found " + rssItems.length + " new feed items");
          rssItems.forEach((item) => {
            let msg = DiscordMsgHelper.ParseGameFeedMsg(item, FEED_WATCHING_ROLE);
            sendMsg(msg, FEED_CHANNEL_ID); // sendMsg is also a promise void
          });
       });
    postFeedPromise.then((_) => DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()); //forked, UpdateLastChackDate() is a promise
    postFeedPromise.catch((e) => console.error(e));
};
// and this is how I'm calling postLatestFeed
postLatestFeed(); // as I'm not currently expecting any return or status/report just catching
```

So do I know what I'm doing here? The code is producing the expected results. I just want to make sure that I'm doing it correctly. Sorry if you don't like the naming, I like capitalizing exported public methods names :3

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Does the code produce the correct output?

Comment: yes it is working as expected

Comment: Great! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: I can see what you mean and how the title can appear to be a bit ambiguous but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it.. as it states exactly what my concern is for the code which is "am I using a feature of a language properly?"

Comment: The syntax looks right and you're using it properly. However it might strike as visually odd to *chain* the first two `then` methods to `DataService.GetLastChackDate()` and then later on to the `postFeedPromise` variable, albeit the same value. Doing one instead of both might provide some readability. Should the chain wait for all `sendMsg` promises to be *resolved* before calling `DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()`? Because that is not yet the case.

Comment: The whole point was *not* to state your concerns about the code in the question title. I've modified it to the best of my understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback...  I can see what you mean by "visually odd" but I need the chaining. I guess you mean to divide the chain into several promises / variables and then chain those variable calls for better readability which is a good point.
As for that last "then" added separately it's intended to be that way because it's forked.. So, like you've already guessed, I don't wanna wait for a resolve to updateLastCheckDate.. I want that last then to be executed simultaneously with the first two chains.

Comment: Oh! sorry my friend I rechecked the guidelines and now understand what you meant @Mast the title you added has nothing to do with what I'm asking but I'll leave it like that because I still don't know what else to put :D I might have understood the purpose of this forum incorrectly so I apologize if my question shouldn't be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote your call to `DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()` makes it appear like there was some coding error that happened. Arrow functions take an expression-only body as its return value. Writing it this way makes it seem like we're awaiting for `DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()` when in fact we don't really care.

```
// The resulting promise will not resolve until UpdateLastChackDate()
// resolves. But the promise is assigned to nothing. Did we mean to
// chain? Did we forget to assign the promise somewhere?
postFeedPromise.then((_) => DataService.UpdateLastChackDate())
```

I would write this to explicitly say that I don't care about the result by placing braces around it.

```
// No return means promise resolves immediately with an undefined.
postFeedPromise.then((_) => { DataService.UpdateLastChackDate() })
```

Alternatively, `DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()` could just be called right after the `forEach()` since we're not awaiting anything from that `then()` either.

And then, we could also write this in async/await form for better readability:

```
const postLatestFeed = async () => {

  try {
    console.log('Checking for new feed...')
  
    const lastCheckDate = await DataService.GetLastChackDate()

    console.log('Last check date is:', lastCheckDate)

    const rssItems = await RssService.GetRssItems(RSS_FEED_URL, lastCheckDate)

    console.log(`Found ${rssItems.length} new feed items`)

    rssItems.forEach((item) => {
      let msg = DiscordMsgHelper.ParseGameFeedMsg(item, FEED_WATCHING_ROLE)
      sendMsg(msg, FEED_CHANNEL_ID)
    })

    DataService.UpdateLastChackDate()
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e)
  }
}

postLatestFeed()
```

Comment: Alright I got you.. yk that line did feel weird tbh.. thanks a lot man appreciate it

Comment: Anything else you found in the example? or should I just mark it as solved?